# `now` becomes slow in a 10 million iterations loop

Tags: performance, raku

I have a [SnowFlake script for Python](https://gist.github.com/ohmycloud/2ae3a27a9c524dafaa96e2ae50b1b5ba), and I convert it to a [Raku](https://gist.github.com/ohmycloud/4e22bce3eb4fa30470570d60fa3ee8a4) module, and call it 10,000,000 times, and it is very slow (file *test.raku*):

```
use IdWorker;

my $worker = IdWorker.new(worker_id => 10, sequence => 0);
my @ids = gather for (1...10000000) { take $worker.get_id() };

my $duration = now - INIT now;
say sprintf("%-8s %-8s %-20s", @ids.elems, Set(@ids).elems, $duration);
```

As @codesections's answer says, it's `now` that takes so much time.

Python takes about 12 seconds, while Raku takes minutes. How can I fix this?

This empty *for* loop takes about 0.12 seconds:

```
for (1...10000000) {
    ;
}
```

And the call `get_id()` on `$worker` takes **minutes**:

```
for (1...10000000) {
    $worker.get_id();
}
```

Comment: System calls should always be assumed to be slow (and thus not called at a higher rate than necessary).

Comment: no worries, just to see is it possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that the issue here does not come from constructing the array but rather from `now` itself – which seems to be oddly slow.

For example, this code:

```
no worries; # skip printing warning for useless `now`
for ^10_000_000 { now }
say now - INIT now;
```

also takes minutes to run.  This strikes me as a bug, and I'll open an issue [Edit: I located [rakudo/rakudo#3620](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/3620) on this issue.  The good news is that there's already a plan for a fix.]  Since your code calls `now` multiple times in each iteration, this issue impacts your loop even more.

Apart from that, there are a few other areas where you could speed this code up:

First, using an implicit return (that is, changing `return new_id;` to just `new_id`, and making similar changes for the other places where you use `return`) is generally slightly faster/lets the JIT optimize a bit better.

Second, the line

```
my @ids = gather for (1...10000000) { take $worker.get_id() };
```

is somewhat wastefully using `gather`/`take` (which adds support for lazy lists and is just a more complex construct).  You can simplify this into

```
my @ids = (1...10000000).map: { $worker.get_id() };
```

(This still constructs an intermediate `Seq`, though.)

Third – and this one is more major from a performance impact, though literally as small as it's possible to be from a code change perspective – is to change the `(1...10000000)` into `(1..10000000)`.  The difference is that `...` is the [sequence operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-sequence_operator) while `..` is the [range](https://docs.raku.org/type/Range) operator.  Sequences have some supper powers compared to Ranges (see the docs if you're curious), but are significantly slower to iterate over in a loop like this.

Again, though, these are minor issues; I believe the performance of `now` is the largest problem.

The *long-term* solution for `now` being slow is for it to be fixed (we're working on it!)  As a temporary workaround, though, if you don't mind dipping into a slightly lower level than is generally advisable for user code, you can use [`nqp::time_n`](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/master/docs/ops.markdown#time-1) to get a floating point number of seconds for the current time.  Using this would make your `get_timestamp` method look like:

```
method get_timestamp() {
    use nqp;
    (nqp::time_n() * 1000).Int;
}
```

With this workaround and the other refactorings I suggested above, your code now executes in around 55 seconds on my machine – still not nearly as fast as I'd like Raku to be, but well over an order of magnitude better than where we started.

Comment: Indeed!, it takes about five minutes to run `now` 10 million times.Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Suggest that you simply capture the value of `now` ahead of time ... once.  On any decent computer, a loop should be able to run 10 million times without "interesting" delay.

Comment: Basically, the TLDR is that the biggest culprit for `now` being slow is the `num` (floating point) → `Rat` conversion, which involves an fair bit of extra math operations (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Calculating_continued_fraction_representations ).

Comment: with new-disp merged to master, `for ^10_000_000 { now }` now take 45 seconds, a big win.